# lsnull или ifnull?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть таблица в ней
4 поля - айди. имя. телефон. емеил/

**телефон и емеил может быть пустым**
нужно сделать запрос чтобы выводил "Поле не заполненно" если в поле телефон и емеил пусто.

Делаю так:

```
select * IFNULL(NULL,'Поле не заполненно') from clients
```

Как правильно прописать?

Comment: При выводе строки проверяйте. `$tel == null ? "Не заполнено" : $tel`. Кстати, если вывести просто пустое поле, то догадаться что поле не заполнено никак нельзя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил
("SELECT  name, IFNULL(phone,'Телефон не заполнен'), IFNULL(email,'Емеил не заполнен') FROM clients");